# IDENTITY_INSERT is ON still showing an error

Tags: sql-server

i am using following code but not working at all..

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MBR_INC_DTL_ ON
INSERT INTO MBR_INC_DTL_
SELECT * FROM MBR_INC_DTL__
```

error message showing..

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MBR_INC_DTL_' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Identity` column must be specified first.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MBR_INC_DTL_ ON

insert into MBR_INC_DTL_
(identity_column_name,
column2,
..
)
select 
identity_column_name,
column2,
..

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MBR_INC_DTL_ OFF
```

Comment: From yesterday i was on trouble . thanks a lot.. for solving my prob.

Comment: @NISAR I am glad it helped you. Try accepting it as your answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, You don't use a column list in your insert statement:

```
insert into tablename (column1, column2, ...)
select ... From ...
```

Comment: i don't know how to thank you... from yesterday i was on trouble . thanks a lot..